# How can I fill a String[][] with spaces?

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating a Battleship game app to learn OOP, Java.  I want to display an "empty sea" for the player to reference to place their fleet.  Here is the beginning of my Gameboard class:

```
public class Gameboard {

private int maxRow = 10;
private int maxCol = 10;
private String[][] gameboard;   // Hits and misses
private String[][] fleetboard;  // Ship locations
private boolean isHuman = false;
private ArrayList <Ship> myShips;
private ArrayList <Point> myShots;

public Gameboard(boolean isHuman) {
    this.isHuman = isHuman;

    String[][] gameboard = new String[maxRow][maxCol];
    fillArray(gameboard, " ");      

    String[][] fleetboard = new String[maxRow][maxCol];
    fillArray(fleetboard, " ");     
}

/*
 * Fills null String[][] with spaces, " "
 * String[][], String -> void
 */
protected void fillArray(String[][] board, String s) {
    // doesn't work TODO
    for (String[] row : board) {
        Arrays.fill(row, s);
    }   

    // also doesn't work TODO       
    for(int i = 0; i < maxRow; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < maxCol; j++) {
            board[i][j] = s;
        }
    }
}
```

I call this in main:

```
myConsole.displayBoard(userBoard.getFleet(), userBoard);
```

userBoard is an instance of Gameboard.  My result is a nullpointerexception because fleetboard is full of nulls (I debugged and saw this).

The current output is :

```
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9    
0 |
```

I want to display a fleetboard full of spaces.  The displayBoard method outputs some info around the fleetboard array so the player can place ships (ex. ship#1 at 4,5, ship#2 at 7,3, etc) similar to the RL game.

Comment: You have class members with the same names as local variables.

Comment: When you call `String[][] gameboard = new String[maxRow][maxCol]; fillArray(gameboard, " ");` in the ctor, you are creating/modifying a local variable. The class member `gameboard` remains uninitialized. If you try to use it elsewhere in your program you will get an error. Same for `fleetboard`.

Comment: I changed it to:
    gameboard = new String[maxRow][maxCol];
  fillArray(gameboard, " ");  
  
  fleetboard = new String[maxRow][maxCol];
  fillArray(fleetboard, " ");

I may switch to using char arrays to make things a bit easier as well..  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main (String[]args) {

        String[][] arrayOfArraysOfSpaces = new String[3][3]; // sample size 3x3

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfArraysOfSpaces.length; i++) {
            Arrays.fill(arrayOfArraysOfSpaces[i], " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Use pre-built method, loop through each array and use the method to fill it with spaces.